# Google PlayStore - Requested permissions do not match core functionality of the app

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, google-play-console, mobile-application

Having trouble with permissions declarations when I publish the app on PlayStore

Built a loan app for unbanked microbusinesses to access credit. The phone data is used for machine learning to predict credit scores using this data
I have specified data collection in the manifest but I keep being rejected in the permissions declarations for the functionalities in my app requiring SMS and Call Log permissions.

Error message:

*"Requested permissions do not match core functionality of the app
You declared SMS-based financial transactions (e.g., 5 digit messages), and related activity including OTP account verification for financial transactions and fraud detection as the core functionality of your app. However, after review, we found that your app does not match the declared use case(s)."*

These are the options:

- Default SMS handler
- Default Phone handler
- Default Assistant handler
- Transactional backup and restore for users and archive for enterprise (time-limited/non-continuous)
- Enterprise archive, CRM, and device management
- Caller ID, spam detection, and blocking
- Connected device companion apps (for example, smartwatch or automotive)
- Cross-device synchronization or transfer of SMS or calls
- SMS-based financial transactions and related activity where access is restricted to financial SMS transactions (for example, 5-digit messages)
- SMS based money management
- Proxy calls
- Services - Carrier
- Services - OEM
- Device Automation
- Physical safety / emergency alert apps (e.g., senior safety)
- Call-based OTP account verification
- Using SMS_CB_RECEIVED for customer communications (e.g., Smart Zone Cast service)
- Write and Show Call History in Dialer
- In-vehicle hands-free use or projected display
- Anti-SMS Phishing

I read the Play Console Help guide. I tried

- Default SMS handler,
- Default Phone handler,
- SMS-based financial transactions and related activity where access is restricted to financial SMS transactions

They are all being rejected and yes, I read through the Play Console Help for exceptions and permitted uses, but other alternative credit scoring apps on the market are able to be listed successfully such as:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mx.com.tala&hl=en_ZA&gl=MX

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.quickcheck.loans&hl=en_ZA&gl=NG

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.branch_international.branch.branch_demo_android&hl=en_ZA&gl=KE

Please help, thank you.

Comment: unfortunately, there's literally nothing we can do for you here, you have to contact the support or consult an expert in this, perhaps a lawyer, nothing we say here can guarantee or even help to get your app approved, because [we don't know](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: @reeco, did you manage to solve this somehow? im currently dealing with same issue.

Comment: @AndrisLaduzans yes i solved it, adding popup dialogue for permissions worked for me ie “Allow XYZ App to access your contacts?” “Deny/Allow”

Comment: @reeco What happens if user chooses DENY, do you finish() your app?

Comment: @AndrisLaduzans I added a popup permission box to fix the issue

Answer (score -1):

It could be useful read the "Data safety" section of the first app, related with SMS and contacts: https://play.google.com/store/apps/datasafety?id=mx.com.tala

As you can see they declare "App functionality, Analytics, Fraud prevention, security, and compliance, Personalization".

My best guess is that you have to choose "Anti-SMS Phishing" and/or "SMS based money management".

Most likely you'll not get the exemption to use the permissions since are both in the black list of Play Store.